# jQuery .append() not working as desired

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my code where I am composing a table:

```
$("#results").append("<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone Number</th></tr>"); 
$("#results").append("<tr><td>John</td><td>1231231234</td></tr>");
$("#results").append("</table>");
```

When I apply border to this table using CSS, it doesnt get applied properly. 
Please refer to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/23NQX/1/

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Take a look at these three lines separately. They don't make sense without context. But they're executed independently.

Comment: Append takes *elements* (which will be automatically created from HTML strings) - it does *not* take partial HTML fragments because it works directly on the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create variable `table`.. append `<tr>` to it... and append the final `table` to result

try this

```
 var table=$('<table>');
 table.append('<tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone Number</th></tr>');
 table.append("<tr><td>John</td><td>1231231234</td></tr>");

 $("#results").append(table);
```

more clear and readable.

append does accept additional arguments, so you can even do

```
 table.append('<tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone Number</th></tr>',"<tr><td>John</td><td>1231231234</td></tr>");
```

but i prefer to go with first...

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/23NQX/5/)

Comment: This is the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Appending unclosed tags will auto close the tag if you don't close them yourself, so in your case it will create 2 tables. So put the string together in one append.

```
$("#results").append("<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone Number</th></tr><tr><td>John</td><td>1231231234</td></tr></table>");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/23NQX/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first create the table and then append rows to the **table**.

Like this:

```
$("#results").append("<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone Number</th></tr></table>"); 
$("#results > table").append("<tr><td>John</td><td>1231231234</td></tr>");
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QSHYE/)

Answer (score 0):

Create the table with your first append, then append to the table

```
$("#results").append("<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone Number</th></tr></table>"); 
$("#results").children("table").append("<tr><td>John</td><td>1231231234</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I always find it helps to think of things the other way around:

```
// create the table
$("<table>")
  // append the header
  .append("<tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone Number</th></tr>")
  // append a row to the table
  .append("<tr><td>John</td><td>1231231234</td></tr>")
  // append the table to the DOM
  .appendTo($("#results"));
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23NQX/6/) showing this works as you want, and is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I offer you to use next structure:

```
$("#results").append($("<table>")
                .append($("<tr>")
                   .append($("<th>").html("Name"))
                   .append($("<th>").html("Phone Number"))
                )
              .append($("<tr>")
                   .append($("<td>").html("John"))
                   .append($("<td>").html("123123123"))
                )

)
```

It's easy to modify and read.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/23NQX/7/

Answer (score 0):

for a simple approach

```
$("#results").append("<table id='table'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone Number</th</tr></table>"); 
$("#table tr:last").after("<tr><td>John</td><td>1231231234</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#results").append("<table id='my_table' border='1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone Number</th></tr></table>"); 
$("#my_table").append("<tr><td>John</td><td>1231231234</td></tr>");
```